# pip install from github doesn't install everything

Tags: github, pip

I want to install a python package from github. It seems that `pip install https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/archive/python-2-head.zip` is the way to go. However, this only installs the python files you can find [here](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/tree/master/newspaper) without the other folders. The package breaks because of this.
If I run `pip install newspaper` (which refers to the same code) the other repos are correctly installed.

I could not get if the problem is coming from `pip` or the package I'm trying to save (I'm kind of new to python packaging :)

The reason I don't want to use `pip install newspaper` is that I'm working on a fork of that code that I want to pull from github to my server directly. I have the same problem with my fork.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the latest snapshot from the github repository with the following command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper.git
```

You can find further information in the [corresponding section](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#git) in `pip`'s documentation.